# no match returned for this regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I am using raw string notation to express a fairly simple regular expression and I am not getting a match object. Shell transcript follows:

```
[~/Documents/Programming/rlm]$ python
python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Aug 25 2013, 00:04:04) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> s = 'bob2323'
s = 'bob2323'
>>> import re
import re
>>> re.match(r'\d+', s)
re.match(r'\d+', s)
>>>
```

Comment: Using `re.match` is equivalent to `r'^\d+'` ie, the string must start with digits.

Comment: it's explained here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `re.search`.  `re.match` only attempts to match starting at the beginning of the string.  However, `re.search` will search through the entire string looking for a substring that matches the pattern.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "bob2323"
>>> re.match(r'\d+', s)
>>> re.search(r'\d+', s)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f4d19beb988>
>>>
```

See [**search() vs. match()**](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match) in the docs for more information

Answer (score 2):

Use [`re.search`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) instead of `re.match`, because `re.match` only matches from the start of the string.:

```
>>> re.search(r'\d+', s)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xb5eefbf0>
```

---

[`re.match` vs `re.search`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match):

> `re.match()` checks for a match only at the beginning of the string,
>   while `re.search()` checks for a match anywhere in the string.